# How to read package.json from webpack plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm currently working on a webpack plugin, and I am trying to find a way to read the `package.json` of the repo calling my plugin. So far, any method I try results in reading the plugins `package.json`.

Is there any way to access that file directly?

Comment: To me it seems a strange approach for a plugin to know about its consumer
But i would also be interested to see if there is a solution for this...

Comment: @FrancisLeigh I'm trying to create a plugin to expose specific dependency versions, along with the main packages version.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the late answer, but I hope this helps others. I was struggling with the same thing and ended up reading the path from `process.env.npm_package_json` and
created variables this way:

```
let packageJson = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(process.env.npm_package_json).toString());
let author = packageJson.author;     // Your Name
let version = packageJson.version;   // 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure about where consumer's package.json is. But you can try this approach out, here webpack context is used:

```
apply(compiler: Compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap('HelloWorldPlugin', () => {
        console.log(`Path where webpack was executed: ${ compiler.options.context }`);
        console.log(require(`${ compiler.options.context }/package.json`));
    })
}
```

Another two approaches that also assume that consumer's package.json is located in the same dir with webpack config:

```
// via **compiler.inputFileSystem**
apply(compiler: Compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap('HelloWorldPlugin', () => {
        console.log(compiler.inputFileSystem.readFileSync('./package.json').toString());
    })
}
// via **process.cwd()**
apply(compiler: Compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap('HelloWorldPlugin', () => {
        console.log(require('path').resolve(process.cwd(), 'package.json'));
    })
}
```

Or you can just pass it through params in consumer's webpack.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    new HelloWorldPlugin({
        packageJsonFile: path.resolve(__dirname, './package.json'),
    })
]
```